# Seek to value stored in memory in radare2

Tags: radare2

Using `radare2`, I am reverse engineering a custom language interpreter.  It stores compiled functions as a list of pointers to language primitives.  I would like to `seek` to these locations, but typing in the hex addresses is very frustrating.  I can't seem to find any syntax for saying "seek to the address stored at the current location".

E.g., say I am looking at the following in visual mode:

```
; UNKNOWN XREFS from entry0 @ 0x400382, 0x400384
; UNKNOWN XREF from entry0 @ +0x82
;-- section..text:
0x004000b0      .qword 0x00000000004002f3 ; aav.0x004002f3    ; [01] -r-x section size 736 named .text
0x004000b8      .qword 0x0000000000000064
0x004000c0      .qword 0x0000000000400301 ; aav.0x00400301
0x004000c8      .qword 0x000000000040032e ; aav.0x0040032e
0x004000d0      .qword 0x000000000040030c ; aav.0x0040030c
. . .
```

The "current location" is at `0x004000b0`, and it stores the value `0x4002f3`, which is where I'd like to seek.  For now, I have to type `g` followed by reading and typing out, or selecting and pasting, the address `0x4002f3`.

Is there some efficient way to say "seek to the value stored at `$$`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one can read a pointer value **using * symbol**
**$$ is alias** for current virtual seek
so *$$ will return the value stored at current seek

you can execute the command and pass the result to seek 
like

```
s `*$$`
```

a simple example showing how to seek to an address stored in 3rd DWORD from current seek

```
[0x01012d6c]> sentry0
[0x01012d6c]> x/4xw
0x01012d6c  0xfffd4be8 0x68586aff 0x01012ee8 0xff99ebe8  .K...jXh........
[0x01012d6c]> s `*$$+8`
[0x01012ee8]>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that, but without the backticks.  Those make a lot of difference!  I can keep "\`*$$\`" in my paste buffer, and use `g` followed by `^V` and `ENTER`.  This works great!

Comment: This seems to ignore if you've loaded it via an offset via `-m`.